# Create an Observable that generates a Single on subscribe, but which stops and reuses a specific value

Tags: retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm using `Retrofit` to make an API call, which returns a `Single`, and I use `onErrorReturn` to convert any exceptions to a default object. I want consumers to see the current value, but if the current value is the default object, I want to try to requery the API and send that result out in addition. To complicate things, I might have multiple subscribers to this.

So, I know the `Retrofit` `Single` has to be converted to a proper `Observable` stream and not just an `onNext`/`onComplete` like a normal `Single.toObservable` would, but I don't know how to requery the API and push the value back out to my previous subscribers using only the `Single` from `Retrofit`.

Right now, I do:

```
fun request(): Observable<Foo> {
  if (behaviorSubject.value == defaultObject) {
    API
      .request()
      .onErrorReturn(defaultObject)
      .subscribe(behaviorSubject)
  }
  return behaviorSubject
}
```

But I know that calling `subscribe` is violating Rx chaining, so I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of that.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the interesting scenario. Here's a solution which I believe covers your requirements. It is longer than your solution but should be safe when it comes to multiple subscriptions.

```kotlin
// subscribe to this observable with one or more subscribers
val requestObservable = replayAndRetry(API.request(), defaultObject)

private fun <T> replayAndRetry(request: Single<T>, defaultValue: T): Observable<T> {
    val responses = BehaviorSubject.create<T>()

    val initialRequest = request
            .onErrorReturnItem(defaultValue)
            .doOnSuccess(responses::onNext)
            .ignoreElement()
            .cache() // run the initial request at most once

    val retryWhenNecessary = Maybe
            .fromCallable { if (responses.value == defaultValue) true else null }
            .flatMapCompletable { request
                    .doOnSuccess(responses::onNext)
                    .ignoreElement()
                    .onErrorComplete() // subject already has the default value
            }
            .toObservable<T>().share() // avoid multiple simultaneous retries

    return responses // source for all responses
            .mergeWith(initialRequest) // will run once and then complete
            .mergeWith(retryWhenNecessary) // will check for default item on every subscription
                                           // will not run simultaneous retries
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I need to investigate this further to understand everything. I'm not familiar with `mergeWith`.